# What is the significance of this folded paper in Brand New Cherry Flavor, episode Hair of the Dog?

Tags: brand-new-cherry-flavor

In Brand New Cherry Flavor, Hair of the Dog when Lisa’s visitors leave, one of them places a piece of paper folded into a star on the table by the door.

What is its significance?  Is this revealed later, or are we supposed to already recognize its significance?

[image: four pointed paper star on a table]

Comment: It's origami four-point ('ninja') star, like this one; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ML732xrZ4O8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In episode 6 it is somewhat revealed what the story telling purpose of the origami star is.

The paper is a kind of calling card of the character and is used later by the narrative to hint the presence of this character to Lisa.

Answer (score 2):

> **What is this folded paper?**

It's a [shuriken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuriken), using the [origami - 折り紙](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origami) technique, such as this one:
[image: Shuriken origami]

From Wikipedia:

> Shuriken were supplementary weapons to the sword or other weapons in a samurai's arsenal, although they often had an **important tactical effect in battle**. The art of wielding the shuriken is known as shurikenjutsu and was taught as a minor part of the martial arts curriculum of many famous schools.
> It is a Japanese concealed weapon that was used as a hidden dagger or metsubushi **to distract or misdirect the enemy**.
> Metsubushi (Japanese: 目潰し, lit. "eye closers") or gantsubushi are a variety of implements and techniques that were used in feudal Japan by samurai police and other individuals to temporarily or permanently blind or disorient an opponent.

---

> **What is its significance?**

According to the historical use of the shuriken, I'd say that the person who put in on the table wanted to convey a message, as a threat, a warning: "*beware, you're about to be hit soon and you won't see it coming. It'll will only be the first blow, more to come.*"

Comment: That doesn't really fit the narrative of the show.

Comment: This serie is "*weird*" (as lack of a better word) and I couldn't get past the 2nd episode. So I just focused on the question asked, not its place (if any) in the plot.

Comment: it just gets weirder….